# I have 8Gb RAM, but the system report 6.8 Gb. How to solve it?

Tags: lubuntu, ram

I have 8Gb RAM, but the system report 6.8 Gb and in bios, it's says 8Gb. I don't have any swap on it. I'm on Lubuntu 18.04 64bit.

[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDN64.png)

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: AMI
       physical id: 0
       version: F.10
       date: 05/17/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 9
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: HMA81GS6AFR8N-UH
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 0
          serial: 825AC392
          slot: Bottom - Slot 1 (left)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: Unknown
          slot: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 192KiB
       capacity: 192KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: d
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           6,8G        1,1G        4,4G         63M        1,3G        5,1G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Comment: Does your video card have its own RAM, or does it steal ram from your system?  Likewise some systems can use system-RAM to store parts of ROM/flash-memory in them to speed up the system as RAM is faster (configurable sometimes in UEFI/BIOS). ie. some of your system memory may be used by your hardware, or it may not - only you or someone with access to your machine hardware can know what you have, and what options you have used.

Comment: Where does "the system report 6.8Gb"?

Comment: @terdon in LXTask and CPUG.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `free -h`.

Comment: @terdon yep, has been edited

Comment: " but the system report 6.8 Gb" no it doesn't. "size: 8GiB". You have 6.8 --available--  to your system. The difference will be assigned/take by your videocard.

Comment: AND... esp with only 8G RAM, you SHOULD have swap... either in a partition or a /swapfile. Swap has nothing to do with what's being reported as total/available RAM.

Comment: ok guys, thanks for ur explanation. I'll add swap on my system.